# organizing some content with ul (to look grid-like)

Tags: css

Hey guys, i need to display all 27 states from brazil in a selection div, I really need to do it using UL.. this is a projection of how they should look:
[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/8726/statesf.jpg](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/8726/statesf.jpg)

And this is a piece of the UL: What would you suggest? can i do that using this markup?

```
<ul class="ufLista">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="AC">AC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="AL">AL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="AM">AM</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="CE">CE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="DF">DF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="ES">ES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="MT">MT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="MS">MS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="MG">MG</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is having those lists nested a necessity? If it was just one list like:

```
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>five</li>
<li>six</li>
<li>seven</li></ul>
```

Then you could style it with:

```
ul { width: 300px; list-style: none; line-height: normal; }
li { float: left; width: 98px; border: 1px black solid; }
```

and get a 'grid' effect pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Since the image is missing, I can only guess, but "grid-like" in the title suggests some kind of table layout. You can set the CSS [`display` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) to certain values which then should trigger table-like display:

> table, inline-table, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-cell, and table-caption
>
> > These values cause an element to behave like a table element (subject to restrictions described in the chapter on tables).

This is described in more detail at [The CSS Table Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display).

Answer (score 1):

To organize data in a grid-like manner, instead of making elements behave like tables, use `<table>`. That's what it was invented for, and it still is the right solution.

Edit: As you need to do it with LIs: It should be no problem to present your markup in a table like manner. Give the inner `<ul>` a `width: 100%, clear: both` and `overflow: auto`. Give the inner `<li>`s `float: left` and either a relative or absolute width that amount to 100% of the ul.

Comment: i'm not afraid of using tables like most of the new "web 2.0 designers" the fact is that i'm trying to fix something that already exists, and it needs to be a list